# ListView Details Insert data in the last column Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, listview

Hi i want to insert data in the last column of my lisview, how do i do that?
i tried using this code `ListView1.SelectedItems(0) = "yes"` or `ListView1.SelectedIndices.Add("Yes")`

[image]

Actually what i want is to update the last column after the initial insertion and how to add items at the beginning of the listview.

Comment: How did you add the data to the other three columns?

Comment: using this code `Dim items() As String = {student.SetStudName, student.SetCourse, student.SetStudID}
        item = New ListViewItem(items)`

Comment: So what happens if you do this: `Dim items() As String = {student.SetStudName, student.SetCourse, student.SetStudID, "Yes"}`

Comment: the data is inserted i want a way to target the last column instead of inserted the whole items.

Comment: Oh you mean you want to update the last column after the initial insertion?

Comment: Yes, and how can i insert listview items before those two?

Comment: Please update your question so that it includes all these specifics; the comments section isn't the right place for it.

Comment: just add another subitem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the following code

```
Dim index As Integer
If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
    index = ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)
    listOfItems(index).SubItems(3).Text = "Qualified"
End If
```